# ncurses getch() behaviour with signals

Tags: c, ncurses

My code sets a timer that sends a SIG_ALRM every x seconds. Then it enters a input-handling loop where it calls getch().

```
    int total_keys = 0;
    while (1) {
        inputchar = wgetch(mywindow);
        mvprintw(LINES - 2, 2, "%d", total_keys++);
        refresh();
        switch (inputchar) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Since I set getch() to be blocking (`wtimeout(mywindow, -1);`), I expected total_keys to only go up when I press a key, but I found that every time the SIG_ALRM is received, getch() returns and total_keys increments. Does anyone know why this works this way?

Edit: This is my handler for SIG_ALRM

```
void alarm_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *si, void *ucontext) {
    timer_t *timeridp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;
    if (*timeridp == *update_timerp) {
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a handler for `SIG_ALRM`? The documentation says "Under the ncurses implementation, handled signals never interrupt getch."

Comment: *This is my handler for SIG_ALRM*  Is your `update()` function async-signal-safe?

Comment: I'm very new to C and didn't know that concept. I'm reading about it and I'm not sure but it probably isn't. Basically my `update()` function calls `malloc` and some curses functions like `wmove`, `winch`, and `printw`. It also sets some data that is used by the main loop. If `printf` and other buffered IO functions are unsafe, I suppose the ncurses counterparts are also unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for an error return and don't process the input when this happens.

```
while (1) {
    inputchar = wgetch(mywindow);
    if (inputchar == ERR) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // report failure somehow
        }
    }
    mvprintw(LINES - 2, 2, "%d", ++total_keys);
    refresh();
    switch (inputchar) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes that works flawlessly, but I wanted to know why getch() gets interrupted in the first place. From the comments I think it's because I shouldn't call ncurses functions from the handler, so maybe I will be better off to just set timeout(0) to make getch non-blocking and just setting a flag from the handler and updating in the main loop.

Comment: Most functions aren't safe to call from a signal handler.